# Poltergeist is not recognising full url

Tags: capybara, poltergeist, capybara-webkit

I am trying to swap over from using `webkit` to `poltergeist` with Capybara feature specs. I have a test like

```
find_link('About')[:href].should == about_path
```

which works fine with webkit, but with poltergeist as the javascript_driver, I get the following error

```
expected: "/about"
     got: "http://127.0.0.1:63361/about"
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybara-webkit is returning the `href` attribute here, whereas poltergeist  (and selenium) returns the property.  The best solution is to change your expectation to use the have_link matcher

```
page.should have_link('About', href: about_path)
```

This has the advantages of working across all drivers, being nicer to read, and also enabling Capybaras retrying behavior to be used.

TL;DR - prefer the Capybara provided matchers over equality checks on attributes whenever possible